# Using HQL to select from multi tables

Tags: hibernate

I have some tables like these: company, device, devicecompany (many-to-many of company & device), user, deviceuser (many-to-many of user & device).
I would like to select device, companyname, compayaddress from userId, so how to I do with hibernate ? 
Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Post your pojo classes.

Comment: Have you mapped `devicecompany` and `deviceuser` or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your class structure, but the basic way is :

```
select u.device.name, u.device.company.name, u.device.company.address
from user u
where u.id=:userId
```

Considering you have already mapped entity device in class user and entity company in class device.